# Is there a way to turn off, completely, the ability to Font Zoom in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often find myself accidentally zooming editor font size in Visual Studio Code.

After scrolling there seems to be a slight continuation even though I'm able to see my target line, and (most often paste) the thing I want in. However, when I hit the ctrl (or command on macOS) the fonts zoom.

I'd prefer to only change the font zoom with the keyboard commands.

Is there a way to turn off mouse scroll font zooming?

Answer (score 5):

In your `settings.json`, just set the following value:

```
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": false
```

> Note that this is actually the default value in the current version of VS Code (`1.67.0`). See [ms/vscode#97137](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97137) for some historical context about the default value.

Comment:  Thanks! Should have found that one myself. 